# Sonata Admin Bundle : change page title

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

A little question : how can I change < title > < /title > with Sonata Admin ?
Everywhere there is "Admin...". And when I override a page with sonata template I got "Admin".

[image]

Thank's.

Answer (score 3):

You can easy do that by override the sonata admin file translation

1- Create folder structure in traslations like this :

[image]

2- then in the `SonataAdminBundle.[your-language-code].yml` file add :

```
Admin: "You Custom title Here"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to override Sonata admin's standard_layout.html.twig file to achieve this.

First, define the file in sonata admin config file.

```
config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml

sonata_admin:    
    templates:
        layout: 'sonata_admin/layout.html.twig'
```

Create a twig file named **layout.html.twig** inside **templates/sonata_admin/** and just paste the **sonata_head_title** block from the bundle.

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block sonata_head_title %}
        {{ 'Admin'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}  //remove this line to get rid of text "Admin"

        {% if _title is not empty %}
            {{ _title|striptags|raw }}
        {% else %}
            {% if action is defined %}
                -
                {% for menu in breadcrumbs_builder.breadcrumbs(admin, action) %}
                    {% if not loop.first %}
                        {% if loop.index != 2 %}
                            &gt;
                        {% endif %}
                        {%- set translation_domain = menu.extra('translation_domain', 'messages') -%}
                        {%- set label = menu.label -%}
                        {%- if translation_domain is not same as(false) -%}
                            {%- set label = label|trans(menu.extra('translation_params', {}), translation_domain) -%}
                        {%- endif -%}

                        {{ label }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```